# How to read a TIBCO message in Grails 3

Tags: grails, jms, grails3

I want to read the messages being sent by TIBCO and process them in my Grails 3 Application. I'm relatively new to Grails 3 and need some assistance in configuring JMS to read messages from the TIBCO topic/queue.
I visited the [documentation site](http://gpc.github.io/jms/latest/guide/receivingMessages.html) but couldn't follow the instructions completely to establish a working example.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at http://realizeideas.net/use-amazon-simple-message-queue-service-within-grails-mircoservices/ - this describes how to configure  Grails + JMS + Amazon SQS. 
For TIBCO you will only need to change connection factory:

```
    TibjmsConnectionFactory connectionFactory = new TibjmsConnectionFactory(...//TIBCO properties)
```

and add correct TIBCO dependencies in build.gradle